# Is there any restriction about the compare function used in qsort()

Tags: c, qsort

I wrote this code snippet to sort an array of strings into an order that minimises their concatenation:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int cmpstr(const void* p1, const void* p2){
    int p1l = strlen((const char*)p1);
    int p2l = strlen((const char*)p2);
    int r = strncmp((const char*)p1, (const char*)p2, p1l<p2l?p1l:p2l);
    if(r == 0 && p1l != p2l){
        if(p1l < p2l){
            return cmpstr(p1, (const char*)p2 + p1l);
        }
        return cmpstr((const char*)p1 + p2l, p2);
    }
    return r;
}

int main(){
    const char* arrstr[] = {"93", "936", "15", "152", "946"};
    int num = sizeof(arrstr) / sizeof(char*);
    qsort(arrstr, num, sizeof(char*), cmpstr);
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        printf("%s\n", arrstr[i]);
    }
}
```

These strings should sort in the order **`15 152 936 93 946`**.  We want `93` to be between `936` and `946` because `936 93` < `93 936` and `93 946` < `946 93` (ignoring the spaces added for clarity).

But the code didn't work as expected. The array didn't get sorted at all, although my tests of `cmpstr()` worked exactly as I expected.

What did I get wrong?

I noticed that when I change the cast part of the `cmpstr()` from `*(char* const*)` to `(char*)`, `qsort()` doesn't work as well.  Why is that?

Comment: "_Is there any restriction about the compare function used in qsort()_" Did you try reading the documentation of [`std::qsort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort)?

Comment: There's no reason to declare that function `static`. That looks like cargo-cult programming where it was used without understanding why.

Comment: @tadman: It might be not understood why, but making functions used in a single compilation unit only `static` is strongly recommended for not polluting the program's namestpace. Sometimes good comes from cargo-cult. E.g. Reggae.

Comment: @Olaf If this was a complex multi-file application the use would be easily justified, but this is a single file program where it's completely out of place. I worry people use these things because they saw someone do it once, and then absorb it into some kind of ritual. That later leads to confusion when your function acts strangely.

Comment: @tad: Does it cause problems in any way? No! So no harm done. Your argument does not make sense and better had pointed out that an empty parameter list is an obsolescense feature and strongly deprecated. It should be `int main(void)`.

Comment: @Olaf When people do things without understanding why there's no immediate problems, but down the road they can cause serious trouble. The naive approach is better than one that's cluttered with poorly understood rituals.

Comment: @tadman: 1) This one will not cause trouble without notification. 2) Instead of discouraging it's usage, one should make sure they understand why it is here 3) We are not a tutoring site; telling people why certain constructs are used (or not) beyond the specific question is off scope on this site. As are such discussions. Feel free to have the last word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comparison function receives pointers to the elements of the array.  Each element is a pointer to char, so you'll get a pointer to a pointer to char.

The comparison logic is also somewhat over-complicated; here's a working version:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int cmpstr(const void* a_, const void* b_)
{
    const char *const *a = a_;
    const char *const *b = b_;
    int la = strlen(*a);
    int lb = strlen(*b);

    if (la == lb) {
        /* same length - sort lexicographically */
        return strcmp(*a, *b);
    }

    if (la < lb) {
        /* a is shorter */
        int result = strncmp(*a, *b, la);
        if (!result) {
            /* a is a prefix of b */
            result = strcmp(*a, *b + la);
        }
        return result;
    }

    /* else, b is shorter - re-enter with arguments swapped,
       and negate the result */
    return -cmpstr(b_, a_);
}

int main() {
    const char* arrstr[] = {"93", "936", "15", "152", "946"};
    const size_t num = sizeof arrstr / sizeof *arrstr;
    qsort(arrstr, num, sizeof *arrstr, cmpstr);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", arrstr[i]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
15
152
936
93
946
```

If you think that my `cmpstr()` above deviates too far from the original, consider this less intrusively-modified code, which uses the recursive comparison that you intended, with a separate wrapper to adapt it to fit `qsort()`:

```
int compare_strings(const char *a, const char *b)
{
    int la = strlen(a);
    int lb = strlen(b);
    int r = strncmp(a, b, la<lb?la:lb);
    if (r == 0 && la != lb) {
        if (la < lb) {
            return compare_strings(a, b + la);
        }
        return compare_strings(a + lb, b);
    }
    return r;
}

int compare_strings_qsort(const void* a_, const void* b_)
{
    const char *const *a = a_;
    const char *const *b = b_;
    return compare_strings(*a, *b);
}
```

I still had to change your variable names, as I find `p1l` and the like hard to read.  I could simplify a bit further, which I think is clearer than both the original function and my first attempt above (but probably needs some comments):

```
int compare_strings(const char *a, const char *b)
{
    const int la = strlen(a);
    const int lb = strlen(b);
    const int r = strncmp(a, b, la<lb?la:lb);

    return (la == lb || r)
        ? r
        : (la < lb)
        ? compare_strings(a, b + la)
        : compare_strings(a + lb, b);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the result I expected is 15 152 936 946 93

Comment: Could you edit the question to explain the sorting criterion, as I've obviously misunderstood what you're trying to achieve?  Thanks.

Comment: @Toby Oh right. I'm still trying to figure out why OP thinks 93 should be sorted last!

Comment: @Ian Abbott sorry about the confusion. I was too sleepy last night

Answer (score 3):

The comparison function passed to `qsort` receives the *address* of the two array elements to compare.  Since each array element is a `char *`, the address of each of these elements is a `char **`.  So you're missing one level of indirection.

You need to cast each parameter to a `char * const *`, then dereference to get the pointer to the string:

```
int cmpstr(const void* p1p, const void* p2p){
    char *p1 = *(char * const *)p1p;
    char *p2 = *(char * const *)p2p;
    ...
}
```

EDIT:

Because you want to call this function recursively, you need a non-recursive wrapper function around your recursive function since the parameters they take are not the same:

```
// internal recursive function that takes two strings
static int cmpstr_int(const char* p1, const char* p2){
    int p1l = strlen(p1);
    int p2l = strlen(p2);
    int r = strncmp(p1, p2, p1l<p2l?p1l:p2l);
    if(r == 0 && p1l != p2l){
        if(p1l < p2l){
            return cmpstr_int(p1, p2 + p1l);
        }
        return cmpstr_int(p1 + p2l, p2);
    }
    return r;
}

// comparison function that extracts desired datatype from void * params
// and passes them to recursive function
static int cmpstr(const void* p1p, const void* p2p){
    const char *p1 = *(char * const *)p1p;
    const char *p2 = *(char * const *)p2p;
    return cmpstr_int(p1, p2);
}
```

Comment: But the cmpstr function worked, when treat p1 as char**, I got segment fault. Now I am more confused.

Comment: @SolskGaer: Either it worked or you get segfault. That's latter is just one possible outcome for your code invoking undefined behaviour. To deepen your knowledge, learn about it. Also, `qsort` is well documented; I'd recommed you read it and learn about pointers. Because that's your problem understanding.

Comment: @Olaf Is it correct that as long as cmpstr's behavior is right, qsort should work properly?

Comment: @SolskGaer: Are you asking if you write correct code, your program behaves correctly? Yes, that's the definition of "correct code".

Comment: @SolskGaer To avoid the segmentation fault, you will need store the "pointer plus length" value in a local variable and pass the address of that variable to the recursive call to `cmpstr`.